# Dual boot OpenBSD with Mint

Tags: openbsd

I want to dual boot mint with OpenBSD. I tried using the instructions here https://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq4.html but it doesn't seem to be working when using a live USB (using  the amd64 download available). It goes to blank screen with the cursor flashing.

Detailed questions:

`# dd if=install*.fs of=/dev/rsd6c bs=1m` is used to create the live USB. What is the debian/Mint/Ubuntu variant of this command?

If my usb stick is `/dev/sdb1` do I use `/dev/rsdb1`?

What file system should the USB stick be?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure about OpenBSD but when I played wtih FreeBSD I got an ISO image for the installer.  If you can do the same, just use Mint's `mint-stick` (on the Menu as "USB Image Writer") to make a bootable USB.

Comment: I tried with the iso using unetbootin and the "USB Image Writer". I'll give mint stick another shot.

Comment: Also, what filesystem was it?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. I didn't get it to dual boot but at least I got an OpenBSD live disk working.

My workaround in case someone needs it:
I used rufus on windows, downloaded a amd64 *.fs image for OpenBSD,set rufus to dd image and the rest was handled by rufus.